# iOS Launch a call from external button

Tags: ios, iphone, hardware, external-accessory

I'm looking into Apple Docs but I can't find anything I need.

I need to create an external hardware button connected to the phone with the lighting port. Whenever I press the button, the phone will launch a phone call to a number saved on the memory of the external hardware. Is it possible or not?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the documentation for [ExternalAccessory](https://developer.apple.com/reference/externalaccessory) . Everything you need/possible is documented there basically.

Edit:
As commented below:

> Be aware that you need to apply and get approved for a special
>   developer program in order to be able to create external accessories.
>   – Duncan C 7 secs ago

Comment: Be aware that you need to apply and get approved for a special developer program in order to be able to create external accessories.